# Dynamically Generating Tests of mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

My codes:

```
['nl', 'fr', 'de'].forEach(function(arrElement) {
  const var1 = 'var1';
  describe(arrElement + ' suite', function() {
    const var2 = 'var2';
    it('This thing should behave like this', function(done) {
      const var3 = 'var3';
      foo.should.be.a.String();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

In the above codes, the `describe` block will run three times. There are three variables: var1, var2, var3. During the three runs, which variable will be created only once? which variable will be created three times?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach()` calls its callback once per array element.

Therefore, your function (and all of its variables and code) will run three times.

Local variables are never shared across multiple calls to their containing function.